# RabbitMQ not working on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, amqp

I can't seem to make RabbitMQ work on a fresh OS X Mountain Lion.
It simply fails to start.

System config below:

- **OS X** 10.8.4
- **Xcode** 4.6.3
- **Brew** 0.9.4

I've upgraded brew and updated all packages:

`brew upgrade`

`brew update`

Installed RabbitMQ using the following command (I've also tried reinstalling it a couple of times without any luck):

`brew install rabbitmq`

Install output below:

```
server1:~ server1$ brew install rabbitmq
==> Downloading http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.1.3/rabbitmq
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/rabbitmq-3.1.3.tar.gz
==> /usr/bin/unzip -qq -j /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.1.3/plugins/rabbitmq_mana
==> Caveats
Management Plugin enabled by default at http://localhost:15672

Bash completion has been installed to:
    /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

To have launchd start rabbitmq at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load rabbitmq now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    rabbitmq-server
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.1.3: 964 files, 23M, built in 2 seconds
```

Tried to start the server using the following command:

`sudo rabbitmq-server start`

Which gives me the following output:

```
Password:

              RabbitMQ 3.1.3. Copyright (C) 2007-2013 VMware, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  ######  ##        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...

BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {badmatch,{error,{no_such_vhost,<<"/">>}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit_error_logger,boot,0,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_error_logger.erl"},{line,42}]},
    {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1,
            [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,488}]},
    {rabbit,run_boot_step,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,487}]},
    {rabbit,'-start/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,453}]},
    {rabbit,start,2,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,453}]},
    {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                        [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]



BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,
       {bad_return,
           {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
            {'EXIT',
                {rabbit,failure_during_boot,
                    {badmatch,{error,{no_such_vhost,<<"/">>}}}}}}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{could_not_start,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{badmatch,{error,{no_such_vhost,<<1 byte>>}}}}}}}}}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
server1:~ server1$
server1:~ server1$ sudo rabbitmq-server start

              RabbitMQ 3.1.3. Copyright (C) 2007-2013 VMware, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  ######  ##        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...

BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {badmatch,{error,{no_such_vhost,<<"/">>}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit_error_logger,boot,0,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_error_logger.erl"},{line,42}]},
    {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1,
            [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,488}]},
    {rabbit,run_boot_step,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,487}]},
    {rabbit,'-start/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,453}]},
    {rabbit,start,2,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,453}]},
    {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                        [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]



BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,
       {bad_return,
           {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
            {'EXIT',
                {rabbit,failure_during_boot,
                    {badmatch,{error,{no_such_vhost,<<"/">>}}}}}}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{could_not_start,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot,{badmatch,{error,{no_such_vhost,<<1 byte>>}}}}}}}}}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I also get the following output when running the `rabbitmqctl status`:

```
server1:~ server1$ rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@localhost ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: [rabbit@localhost]

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- localhost: [{rabbitmqctl1391,49583}]

current node details:
- node name: rabbitmqctl1391@server1
- home dir: /Users/server1
- cookie hash: 5K+867WqzDShyhtWE7X49Q==
```

Comment: can you backup brew directory, remove all brew-related stuff and try to install again. On the same configuration i can't reproduce problem, but no_such_vhost,<<"/">> looks damn strange

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It really helped me out.

Comment: I am having now the same issue. I have a hunch that this is caused by a lock file held by root when rabbitmq was run as sudo (accidentally) `/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 80: /usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost.pid: Permission denied`